# Fixed cookies bar push down content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have a cookie bar and want it to be fixed on the top of the page until the user has poushed a button to Close it. I want the outher content on the page to be pushed down so the user can se the whole page even if the user hasent closed the information bar. Is that posible whith just css or how d can I do it easy?

Comment: If the HTML of your cookie bar is before your content, it should push the content down naturally, like so https://jsfiddle.net/dk45jbzz/2/

Comment: The cookie bar is going to be fixed to the top when scrolling (css: position: fixed;)